# Add links to custom pages in the keystone Admin UI

Tags: keystonejs

I am using keystone 4.0 beta version and want to be able to add links to my own routes and templates, which are not keystone lists, in the admin UI. I found the following example to do so in the navigation (by adding an object instead of string):

```
keystone.set( "nav", {
  "content": [
    "posts",
    "post-categories",
    "enquiries",
    {
      label: "reports",
      key: "reports",
      path: "/api/reports"
    },
  ]
});
```

I guess this worked in older versions but since the new version uses React it only changes the URL in the browser without actually redirecting to the page. Is there any way to workaround this?

Comment: Could you please paste a link to the example you found?

Comment: I found it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keystonejs/6fHfkrSeRWs) and [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1645)